# laravelcollective: add extra attribute to each options(Form::Select)

Tags: php, laravel-5

```
<select class="form-control" id="user" name="car">
  <option value="0" selected="selected">Select Cars</option>
  <option dta-img='1.jpg' value="134">Volvo</option>
  <option dta-img='2.jpg' value="135">Noah</option>
  <option dta-img='3.jpg' value="136">Marcidis</option>
  <option dta-img='4.jpg' value="143">London Express</option>
</select>
```

My array for options :

```
public function guardianList()
    {
      $list = ["Select Cars"];
        foreach ($carss->all() as $car) {
            $list[$car->id] =  $car->name;
        }
        return $list;
}

   Form::select('car',$list, null, null);
```

How can i add extra dynamic html attribute to all options?
I want to show image infront of every option in jquery select2. For that i need to send image from Form::Select(). I there any easy way to do that without using marcos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved the issue:
Pass array in the 4th param.

```
$opt_attributes = collect($guardians->all())
        ->mapWithKeys(function ($item) {
            return [$item->id => ['data-img' => $item->photos->last()->name]];
        })->all();
```

make a array linke this and pass it as 4th parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly since which version, but laravelcollective/html 5.8 version takes optionParameters as fifth parameter, not 4th